# Protocol error:packet too long :1349676920 ssh

Tags: ssh

I have tried to activate the ssh for user 
putty is ok and work
but by ssh vi the ssh secure shell program the following error is received:
Protocol error:packet too long :1349676920

Comment: This is too vague. Please [edit] your post to explain in more detail what you're doing, what actual program is running, how you configured it and invoked it, and how you're getting this error message.

Comment: It sounds almost like a device (switch/router/nic) is faulty and corrupting data.